# ASP.NET C# Unable to Link To Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I will try to be short and concise.

I started doing a web app for an inventory/sales little internal project so I could learn and develop on c# so apologies for the dumb question.

What I have so far is my AccountController for accounts(db query), and my DBController for database, as well as routing set on Program.cs.

In the Index.cshtml i have set a button to try out the login window but for some reason it never jumps to the controller, after searching for over 2 days and trying I gave up.
This is what I have.

`This is my Program.cs`

```
public partial class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
       Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
           {
               webBuilder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
               {
                   var connectionString = hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default");

                   services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                   {
                       options.UseMySql(connectionString, new MySqlServerVersion(new Version())); // Replace with your MySQL version
                   });


                   // Add other services here
               });
               webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
           });
}

public class Startup
{
    // This class can be left mostly empty in .NET 6
    // The ConfigureServices method will be called in Program.cs
}
```

`This is my Index.cshtml`

```
@if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <form method="post" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" class="login-form-container">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" class="login-input" /><br />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" class="login-input" /><br />
    <button type="submit" class="login-button">Login</button>
</form>
}
else
{
    <p>Hello, @User.Identity.Name! You are logged in.</p>
    <a asp-controller="AccountController" asp-action="Logout">Logout</a>
}
```

And Finally
Please note that the adding of the "Route" was my last attempt to try it.

`This is my AccountController.cs`

```
using Bookshop.ContextDB;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


namespace Bookshop.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;

        public AccountController(AppDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string username, string password)
        {
            var user = await _dbContext.users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.username == username);

            if (user != null && VerifyPassword(password, user.password))
            {
                // it worked
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View();
        }

        private bool VerifyPassword(string inputPassword, string hashedPassword)
        {
            // To check better password reqs
            return inputPassword == hashedPassword;
        }
    }

}
```

I have the AccountController on a Controller folder, have removed from there to try. Have tested on a simplified Controller, tried to implement directly on the index.cshtml.

I belive my problem will be in the Program.cs as the routing seemed to be made under startup.cs but that does not exist anymore in .net6.

Everywhere I turn does it differently and there are many logics, I am trying a few and without luck.

`Update(Still unable to link to Controller)`

Changed ASPControl to the controller full name(from my research it is wrong to do it this way)

Have placed the AccountController on the main project Folder, still no luck.

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/login-style.css" />
</head>


@if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <form method="post" asp-controller="AccountController" asp-action="Login" class="login-form-container">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" class="login-input" /><br />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" class="login-input" /><br />
    <button type="submit" class="login-button">Login</button>
</form>
}
else
{
    <p>Hello, @User.Identity.Name! You are logged in.</p>
    <a asp-controller="AccountController" asp-action="Logout">Logout</a>
}
```

Comment: In your View, you have User.Identity.IsAuthenticated. What kind of Identity Server are you using in your application? In your ConfigureServices, there's no reference to an IdentityServer.

Comment: seems like it should be: asp-controller="AccountController" instead of asp-controller="Account"  (in the form...)

Comment: have you tried with  pcalkins's suggestion? does it work?

Comment: @pcalkins I Tried it no luck. But all that i have been reading is that when it is definned as a Controller you only need the first part when calling in anyway.

Comment: @SoftwareDveloper When I did the login i saw this example but haven't gone on the Identity side but it is going into the ASP.

Comment: Where is the services.AddController...

Comment: @Zinov Just added onto the Program.Cs (Have never see that btw) Still no luck, not going into controller

Comment: maybe try with: asp-controller="api/Account"?  The route attribute there seems to want "api/" first... as is your helper will generate an action of "Account/Login"

Comment: I think you may be missing some things in Program.cs (..calls like app.UseRouting();)  Not sure that "[Route]" attribute is correct either... maybe see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis  (I've always used standard razor routing... it maps the endpoints via endpoints.MapRazorPages();..)  You can then just use asp-action and it maps method according to POST or GET.

Comment: Could you upload a minimal example that could reproduce the issue?